# Каких правил придерживаться, чтобы правильно проектировать классы и программу на Java?

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, шаблоны

Изучаю сейчас Java, знакомый с принципами ООП.

Каких еще правил нужно придерживаться чтобы правильно проектировать классы и программу в общем? (Чтобы не стыдно было показать мой код другим)

Мне посоветовали почитать о SOLID

Comment: Почитайте "Effective Java" Джошуа Блоха, "Чистый код" и "Чистая архитектура" Роберта Мартина.

Comment: а потом прочитайте Elegant Objects и снова задумайтесь об ООП

Comment: @dSH ну вот зачем вы так?

Answer (score 10):

Это мое личное мнение, и это не относится даже к программированию. Это общий подход к решению проблем.

---

Я только хотел сказать, что нельзя **слепо** придерживаться никаких правил, точнее немного не так, правила нужны чтобы не совершить определенные ошибки и любым правилом можно пренебречь, если Вы понимаете что Вы делаете или зачем нужно тот или иное, как вы выразились, правило. Правила помогают принять верное решение не включая мозг - это да, но не всегда так можно, иногда нужно и самому подумать.

Слыхали такое ?

> все правила созданы для того, чтобы их нарушать

Все шаблоны хорошо работают только в определенных ситуациях, и Вы сами каждый раз думать, какое решение в данной ситуации будет оптимальным. Иначе был бы один шаблон.

---

Еще вот для **размышлений на тему**

Никто заранее не знает вашей цели.

Есть такая диаграмма, она сильно упрощена, но поэтому и понятна:

```
  $
  /\
 /  \
t----q

t=время
q=качество
$=цена
```

Вы можете сделать программу быстро и качественно, но это будет очень дорого, т.к. вам понадобится целый штат специалистов, умеющих работать в команде.

Вы можете сделать программу дешево и быстро, но тогда пострадает качество. т.к. денег у Вас на специалистов нет и вы идете на фриланс биржу где делают все за 10 баксов. На архитектуру тут нет времени.

И вы можете сделать программу дешево и качественно но один и очень долго.

[image: circles]

Спасибо [Alexander Chernin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/235611/alexander-chernin) за картинку

Конечно и из этого найдется исключение.

---

UPD: Сегодня перечитал Ваш вопрос и решил вот еще что добавить:

Дизайн кода и архитектура программы это не совсем одно и то же. Они похожи но находятся на разных уровнях иерархии. Дизайн кода он более локален, в идеале, код решает какую-то одну задачу, "откинув за скобки" все то, что не относится к ней. Группа классов, необходимых для решения локальной задачи это **Программный модуль**, так вот архитектура программы это граф взаимодействия этих модулей.

"Увидеть" архитектуру сквозь код это надо еще уметь.

---

Про не стыдно показать (это кстати тоже можно отнести к требованиям, т.е. не всегда это необходимо :) )

В зарубежной литературе, для описания качества кода встречается термин **wtf/sec** т.е. количество гневных восклицаний читающего код в единицу времени.

Пишите код чтобы он читался. Когда посреди одного действия вдруг описано другое - это может вызвать негодование у читающего. Как будто автор книги постоянно книги перескакивал бы с темы на тему каждое предложение.

Старайтесь не использовать ["капитанские"](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) (переменные с именем `data` или метод с названием `method` это очень длинный список), переменная должна отражать то, что в ней хранится, а метод-то что он делает.

Так же с осторожностью стоит использовать сокращенные названия для методов, переменных, классов и всего остального чему вы придумываете название, в момент выбора имени лучше несколько раз подумать, я иной раз по пол часа обсуждаю с коллегами название для метода.

Вы можете очень хорошо ориентироваться в коде в момент решения конкретной задачи, потому что у Вас в голове загружен контекст, у читающего его нет, как и вероятно у Вас же в будущем, когда Вы будете заниматься другой задачей и вдруг Вас попросят починить вон ту ошибку в коде проекта, который вы же и писали 2 года назад.

Правильные названия для методов позволят читающему даже не открывать их листинг, наткнувшись на них где-то в коде. В двойне плохо если метод называется адекватно, но делает нечто иное, не то что написано в названии. Я тут пишу про метод, но то же самое относится к любому участку кода, будь то переменная, класс или пакет.

---

P.S. Извините, что может быть пишу слегка сумбурно, не умею я это.

Comment: Вот эту картинку можно вставить http://i.piccy.info/i9/137e8c44613024e370171c974a54a412/1505413926/18758/1161865/pamiatka_zakazchyku.jpg

Comment: @AlexanderChernin спасибо, буду у компа - вставлю :) я тут с телефона опусы пишу пока час на работу еду :) с него не удобно картинки добавлять

Comment: За написание с телефона таких текстов надо сразу золотую медаль давать )